# For some reason I am getting: fetch(...).then(...).then(...).map is not a function

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api, map-function

```
function getResults(querySearch) {
  api.pageNum += 1;
  refs.list.innerHTML = '';
  const imgBlock = fetch(
    `https://pixabay.com/api/?image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&q=${querySearch}&page=${api.pageNum}&per_page=12&key=${api.key}`,
  )
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(pic => pic.hits)
    .map(item => template(item).join(''));
  refs.list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', imgBlock);
}
```

I'd like to use a handlebars template to each item mapped, but for some reason, I keep getting:

> "fetch(...).then(...).then(...).map is not a function"

Here's a full code:

```
import './styles.css';
import template from './templates/template.hbs';

const api = {
  key: '#',
  querySearch: '',
  pageNum: 1,
};

const refs = {
  list: document.querySelector('.gallery'),
  form: document.querySelector('#search-form'),
  input: document.querySelector('input'),
};

refs.input.addEventListener('input', catchInput);

function catchInput(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
  getResults(refs.input.value);
  console.log(refs.input.value);
}

function getResults(querySearch) {
  api.pageNum += 1;
  refs.list.innerHTML = '';
  const imgBlock = fetch(
    `https://pixabay.com/api/?image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&q=${querySearch}&page=${api.pageNum}&per_page=12&key=${api.key}`,
  )
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(pic => pic.hits)
    .map(item => template(item).join(''));
  refs.list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', imgBlock);
}
```

HANDLEBARS

```
    <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="{{webformatURL}}" alt="{{webformatURL}}" />
    <div class="stats">
        <p class="stats-item">
            <i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>
            {{likes}}
        </p>
        <p class="stats-item">
            <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
            {{visibility}}
        </p>
        <p class="stats-item">
            <i class="material-icons">comment</i>
            {{comments}}
        </p>
        <p class="stats-item">
            <i class="material-icons">cloud_download</i>
            {{downloads}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tip: You can't just slap `map()` on the end of a `then()` chain.

Comment: Can you rewrite this as an `async` function? That'd make the code a lot less convoluted.

Comment: It's usually better to define functions like `catchInput` before they're referenced in other code, as in the `addEventListener` call. That could be an error.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of things you can do with Promises, but `map()` is not one. You can easily rewrite this, though:

```
function getResults(querySearch) {
  api.pageNum += 1;
  refs.list.innerHTML = '';

  const imgBlock = fetch(
    `https://pixabay.com/api/?image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&q=${querySearch}&page=${api.pageNum}&per_page=12&key=${api.key}`,
  )
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(json => {
      let imgBlock = json.hits.map(item => template(item).join(''));

      refs.list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', imgBlock);
    })
}
```

Remember `imgBlock` *is a Promise* and is of absolutely no use to `insertAdjacentHTML` until it's resolved. You were executing that code prematurely, it *must* be put into the `then` callback.

If you can use `async`, this code is really simple and a lot easier to follow:

```
async function getResults(querySearch) {
  api.pageNum += 1;
  refs.list.innerHTML = '';

  const data = await fetch(
    `https://pixabay.com/api/?image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&q=${querySearch}&page=${api.pageNum}&per_page=12&key=${api.key}`,
  );

  let json = await data.json();
  let imgBlock = json.hits.map(item => template(item).join(''));

  refs.list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', imgBlock);
}
```

Anything you can do to reduce nesting in JavaScript often turns out to be a huge win, so I'd recommend this approach.

Comment: There's might be a chance I have made a mistake somewhere else, cause after your help with refactoring, I still looking for a way out of the problem...could you please check my code? i have updated a question

Comment: This is the way out of that problem. There's two mistakes in your code: Using `map()` on a Promise and using a value before the promise has been resolved.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at eval (index.js?2615:29)"

Comment: that's what I am getting, sir

Comment: `data.json()` must be `await`ed too. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json))

Comment: @CherryDT They should both be up-to-date now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I am still getting errors for some reason, what else can we do?

Comment: "getting errors" doesn't help us. You need to be more specific. You may need to step through this in a debugger to see what's wrong.

Comment: alright, the purpose is to fetch the data from the rest API and apply a handlebars template at each object of the array (.hits) - what should i change in my code for that?